# How can I include the ObjectID key from MongoDB in the JSON response?

Tags: go

After of MongoDB FindOne() function I need to take the ObjectID and use it in the http.ResponseWriter

```
    documento, err := bd.IntentoLogin(t.Email, t.Password)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Usuario y/o Contraseña inválidos", 400)
        return
    }

    jwtKey, err := jwt.GeneroJWT(t.Email)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Ocurrió un error al intentar generar el Token correspondiente. "+err.Error(), 400)
        return
    }

    resp := models.RespuestaLogin{
                               ____________________________________      
                         <<<<< Here I need to Include the ObjectID
                               ____________________________________
        Nombre: documento.Nombre,
        Apellidos: documento.Apellidos,
        Token: jwtKey,
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
```

What's the right syntax if I need to add this ObjectID into the JSON struct ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
type RespuestaLogin struct {
    ID        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Nombre    string        `bson:"nombre"`
    Apellidos string        `bson:"apellidos"`
    // rest of your fields...
}

resp := models.RespuestaLogin{
    ID: bson.ObjectId("112233"),
    Nombre: documento.Nombre,
    Apellidos: documento.Apellidos,
    Token: jwtKey,
}
```

Your function `db.IntentoLogin()` must return a string to insert as ObjectID or something to fit [`ObjectId` type](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#ObjectId).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but in your example you use a literal

ID: bson.ObjectId("112233"),

I need to know how use the DB object instead